# Place holder image instead of thumbnail product image in magento 2.1.9

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, product-images, placeholder

I have installed Magento 2.1.9 and import product via csv. After import

I tried:

> clear Cache
>
> Static-content generate
>
> Reindex
>
> Setup upgrade
>
> catalog Image resize
>
> remove all /var/* content
>
> compile also

Still showing a thumbnail place holder image in  **frontend** and **admin**.

The Product Page "Images And Videos" is showing the image Correctly.

Suggest me, how to fix this

Answer (score 1):

Please start solving your problem by checking if you are in the correct Store View in the drop down in the upper left of your backend/admin page.
[image: storeview selector]